# I am looking for a word resembling "Coralline"

Tags: synonyms

We are two partners about to launch a product that is currently called "Coralline". We are inspired from the animal and its habitat in underwater. Since this will be an international product I am having second thoughts about this word because it is hard to pronounce and transcribe for non-native English speakers. Also I believe it is not a commonly used word in English so even native English speakers will not grasp the meaning at first glance.

I am looking for a word that resembles Coralline or coral reefs, like "seaweed" etc. My criteria are:

- Unique
- Easy to remember
- Easy to spell

Any help would be much appreciated.

Additional information: We ended up with Coralline through a research on fractals. That might be a cue for any suggestion.

We are going with underwater/reef theme some words related to that can also help.

Comment: Corals are animals, of the phylum *Cnidaria,* not plants at all. Only some kinds are stony and so (very slowly) build reefs--which are paradises for divers but feared by sailors, so connotations cut both ways.

Comment: What is the meaning you seek to convey?

Comment: The Nate we moved from the fractal shape and the habitat of Corallines

Comment: Unique in what context? Random strings of letters are likely to be unique, but difficult to remember and spell.  Meaningful words are easier to remember and spell, but they are meaningful because they are already associated with other things. Can you use *reef*? Are you looking for something more like *Flooz*, *xkcd*, or *Apple*?

Comment: Jejorda2 unique in a way that it is not used by any other widely known brand. Simply if you don't know a brand with the name you will suggest it should be fine. Reef is a nice suggestion we are already using it for a different product. Thank you. We are looking for something like Apple if I have to choose from your examples.

Comment: Ermanen the features of our product and the context is not relevant at this time. We are merely looking for synonyms or alternatives that would fit in an underwater life or a fractal theme. (Urunumuz hakkinda detay vermek istemiyorum cunku onerilecek kelimelerin contextten ve urunden bagimsiz olmasini istiyorum.)

Answer (score -3):

With one less L the word is well-known in English, because of this book.

[image: book]